# Angularjs - change templates without changing url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, url

new to Angular and JS so my jargon may be off.

Within a certain section of a page I would like to load in different templates depending on the user clicks ***without*** changing the URL path. I know how to use $routeProvider with ng-view but that requires a URL change to load the related template.

I would also like to add a back link within this specific section so the user can travel back a step.

Any ideas? I couldn't find any questions similar to mine but I may be searching with the incorrect terms. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: did u check `ng-include` ?

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha I haven't but that looks like the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using ng-include. This allows you to include chunks of html code from another location. You could then use ng-show/hide to display the desired piece or ng-if if you would prefer that it is left out of the dom if not required

Answer (score 3):

And for the back button, you would have to keep a history array with past clicks/links and push pop from that as you click and click back. The "complete" solution would look similar to:

index.html

```
<html ng-app="app">
...
<div ng-controller="myController">

  <button ng-click="setCurrentView('tem1')">Template 1</button>
  <button ng-click="setCurrentView('tem2')">Template 2</button>
  <button ng-click="setCurrentView('tem3')">Template 3</button>

  <div ng-include="tem1.html" ng-show="currentView==tem1"></div>
  <div ng-include="tem2.html" ng-show="currentView==tem2"></div>
  <div ng-include="tem3.html" ng-show="currentView==tem3"></div>

  <button ng-click="goBack()">Back</button>

</div>
...
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.currentView='tem1';
  var history=[];

  $scope.setCurrentView=function(view){
    history.push($scope.currentView);        
    $scope.currentView=view;
  }

  $scope.goBack=function(){
    $scope.currentView=history.pop();
  }
}]);
```

Comment: That's really helpful, if I had more rep I'd up-vote this. Thanks.